# Does passing string instead of integer to bind_param in php do a type cast?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have following php code:

```
$post_id = $_GET["id"];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT title FROM `posts` WHERE id=?");
$creator = "Anupam";
$stmt->bind_param("i", $post_id);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

This works perfectly fine for webpages like `http://localhost2/post.php?id=3202`. But I noticed that even pages like `http://localhost2/post.php?id=3202XYZ` or `http://localhost2/post.php?id=3202xyz/css/style.css` work like anything after `3202` was stripped off.

Does `bind_param` do a type cast to `int` for `i` parameters? php docs don't mention anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

[Looking at the source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-8.1.1/ext/mysqli/mysqli_api.c#L218) for `bind_param`, we can find the following line in the `i` case:

```
bind[ofs].buffer = &Z_LVAL_P(param);
```

Here, `Z_LVAL_P` refers to the L(ong) VAL(ue) of the P(ointer) `param` - "long" being the C integer data type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

Check the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f25a380fa44ba850453a1435a316309ae9745a33/ext/mysqli/mysqli_api.c#L218):

```c
bind[ofs].buffer = &Z_LVAL_P(param);
```

[Z_LVAL_P](https://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php5/zvals/basic_structure.html) gets the integer value.